# Jelastic MySQL uses a lot of memory when idle

Tags: mysql, memory, jelastic

I'm using jelastic with mysql, the problem is, why mysql node uses 350+mb of RAM (3 cloudlets) on idle? I have another enviroment with Postgresql and it uses only 49mb (1 cloudlet) on idle too. Tested with two differents jelastic partners. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't really about Jelastic, but more about database servers and how they work. Especially in the case of MySQL you can load various different engines, and each one uses some RAM simply to be ready to do work for you.

You can edit my.cnf, so if there are engines loaded that you don't need you can reduce your memory footprint by disabling them.

But more broadly speaking, 384MB is not a huge amount of RAM...

In terms of Jelastic's auto vertical scaling, on database servers you will usually see this relating to CPU scaling. RAM usage is quite static for many database server workloads, with the biggest factors being database size and server configuration settings (e.g. buffer sizes in my.cnf). So the scaling up/down comes from handling CPU spikes due to intensive queries (e.g. unindexed / full table scans).